# Site not Resolving

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I managed to deploy my ASP.NET to Google Cloud Compute Engine, but the site is not resolving or cannot be reached. I have tried the code below on Cloud Shell and the outcome follows.

```
# - address returned by command above.
xxxxxx@cloudshell:~ (sssssss)$ dig ${dns-name} @10.18.26.218 

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> name @10.18.26.218
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

The IP address is the External IP of the Instance

Answer (score 0):

This statement is categorically wrong:

> The IP address is the External IP of the Instance

---

`10.18.26.218` is a private IP address, because the whole `10.` range is a private IP address range:

```
10.0.0.0/8 IP addresses: 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255
```

you'd have to reserve and assign an external IP address, in order to enable access from external.

[RFC-1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) explains the "Address Allocation for Private Internets" in detail.

---

most likely also `tcp:80` and/or `tcp:443` would need to be opened on the firewall... but while using such a private IP address, which is not publicly route-able, the request won't even reach the firewall (just to explain, why exactly I've down-voted the other answer, which had been deleted quickly).

Comment: The actual IP address begins with 104

Comment: How do i go about opening the tcps noted above